# How to delete the folders created with 2016-04-03 to 2016-10-4 date names

Tags: shell-script, command-line, date, rm

I am looking for script or command to delete a folder which was created one day only (means single day) which starts with this format: 2016-04-03.tar.gz ... 2016-09-30.tar.gz. I want to delete folders that are 60 days old.

Comment: I edited your post to hopefully clarify the meaning. Please double-check that I captured your intention correctly. Also, are you trying to run a script every day that deletes one 60-day-old folder/file, or any files that are over 60 days old?

Comment: ex. Folder name format is 2016-04-03.tar.gz ... 2016-09-30.tar.gz. in this range folder created on oct7th all these folder. If i can use "find" command but find command works with created time. So I am look script to delete the those folders older then 60 days.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you've asked. It will search for all directories starting with the pattern "2016-??-??.", and if they are older than 60 days it will delete them.

```
find 2016-??-??.* -maxdepth 0 -daystart -mtime +60 -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

On the other hand, in the comments you've hidden a suggestion that you might actually be confusing tar files with folders. If you want to delete tar files you can use a construct like this:

```
find 2016-??-??.tar.gz -daystart -mtime +60 -type f -delete
```

<sub>The difference here shows why it's important to edit your question to keep it up to date, rather than hiding information in the comments.</sub>

Comment: Sorry to late reply, roaima. the above command not working. It not giving any out put. Here is requirement i have bulk .tar.gz folder which crated same date with sequence date (from 2016-04-01 to 2016-10-09). Now I am looking script or command i want to delete these folders which older then 60 day. (folders name )

Comment: @user if it's not working please edit your question to give a specific example of a file or folder. Your question and your comments contradict each other so please ensure you provide a definitive question from which answers can be written

Comment: ex. path /mnt/test/folders are created single day one folder with date format like 2016-04-01 to 2016-09-30 six month folders crated. I have run command find with -exec tar option it created all folder with same name .tar.gz. in same day (means i have run that command 2016.10.1). when I check use 'll' command it show creation date (2016-10-1). Now I am want to delete these folders older then 60 days...........

Comment: If I use find command it will check with creation date or modification date only as i know and I have tried this find /mnt/siteminder/ -maxdepth 1 or 0 -name '*.tar.gz' -mtime -30 , it giving all the folders in that path. (all six month folders). Because it created date 2016-10.01. I hope i have give full details. Please let me know how delete these folders.

Comment: @user. PLEASE. As previously asked, add your new information to your question. Don't put it here in the comments.